# How to sum times in a text file using command-line?

Tags: scripting, numeric-data

I have a text file containing flight times, hours and minutes separated by colon sign, one per line:

```
00:50
00:41
00:43
00:50
01:24
```

I am currently using Apple's Numbers application with a simple formula to calculate the total time (result being **4:28** for the example data above).

However, I was wondering if there is an easier way to achieve this. A perl script would work all right, but how about using Unix shell commands and/or scripting? I am basically looking for anything short and simple.

Yes, I can manage with Numbers, but this would be nice to know and learn :).

p.s. Posting perl script to achieve this in case someone else needs it:

```
#! /usr/bin/perl
while (<>) {
  chomp;
  ($hours, $minutes) = split (/:/, $_);
  $totalhours += $hours;
  $totalminutes += $minutes; 
}
while ($totalminutes > 59) {
  $totalhours++;
  $totalminutes -= 60;
}
printf ("%d:%02d\n", $totalhours, $totalminutes);
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As you note, there are many possibilities.  The following versions with awk are roughly equivalent to the perl you included with your question:

1. (with GNU awk):

   ```
   awk -F : '{acch+=$1;accm+=$2;} ENDFILE { \
   print acch+int(accm/60)  ":" accm%60; }' [inputfile]
   ```
2. (with "POSIX" awk):

   ```
   awk -F : '{acch+=$1;accm+=$2;print acch+int(accm/60) \
                ":" accm%60; }' [inputfile] | tail -1
   ```

Comment: Useful for calculating cumulative times (without the `tail` pipe). +1

Answer (score 2):

A "one-liner" version in Perl:

```
perl -F: -lane '$a+=$F[0]*60+$F[1];END{printf "%02d:%02d\n",$a/60,$a%60}' file
```

Comment: Added `ct () { perl -F: -lane '$a+=$F[0]*60+$F[1];END{printf "%02d:%02d\n",$a/60,$a%60}' "$@"; }` to my `.bash_profile`. Nice!

Comment: perfect! if i get hours:minutes:seconds this will be the code `perl -F: -lane '$a+=$F[0]*3600+$F[1]*60+$F[2];END{printf "%02d:%02d:%02d\n",$a/3600,$a/60,$a%60}' file`

Answer (score 2):

This should work in any POSIX-compatible shell:

```
#!/bin/sh
# usage: time-add.sh < times.txt
sum=0
while IFS=: read -r hours minutes; do
    sum=$(($sum + $hours * 60 + $minutes))
done
total=$(($sum / 60)):$(($sum % 60))
echo $total
```